# In JSP, how to pass ArrayList using anchor tag?

Tags: jsp, object, tags, anchor

I am a total newbie in JSP. 
All I can do is receive data from form tags from another web page.
I don't know any MCV(MVC?) nor custom tag, session, cookies or anything deeper than that.

All I need is to pass an ArrayList to another dynamically generated JSP page using an anchor tag.
Here is the specification.

Basically I have a 2-dimensional ArrayList.
The first dimension is iterated and listed in the first JSP page.

So the first JSP page would look like this:

---

This is ArrayList1. The size is 23.

This is ArrayList2. The size is 19.

This is ArrayList3. The size is 12.

..

..

..

This is ArrayList(n). The size is 1.

---

Each line is an anchor tag and when a user clicks it, 
the corresponding ArrayList is passed to the second JSP page.

The second JSP page, all it does is receive an ArrayList and just iterate through it and list the data in it.
So there needs to be only one "second JSP page" because it will receive only one ArrayList at a time. It just needs to be dynamic.

I know how to iterate through an ArrayList in a JSP page.
What I don't know is how to pass ArrayLists to another JSP page using an anchor tag.

Any tips or methods are welcome. I did some searching of my own, but all the comments are just too high-level for me. I'd appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should not do this way. Instead, you can do the following way. It is easier and more possible.

Idea:
 - set all arraylist to

```
request.setAttribute("arraylist1",Arraylist1);
request.setAttribute("arraylist2",Arraylist2);
.....
```

- In each anchor tag, you place an id to recognize which link is click

```
(e.g. <a href="b.jsp?id=arraylist1">your link </a>)
```

- In the b.jsp, get id parameter which this line of code

```
String selectedLink = request.getParameter("id")
```

- Compare if selectedLink = arraylist1
- List selectedArray = (List)request.getAttribute(selectedLink);

Hope this useful

NathanPhan

Comment: Thanks for the reply!! I tried something similar to your answer. I passed each ArrayList's Key to the other JSP page. And in the second JSP page, I call the corresponding ArrayList from MySQL again. I don't know if this is the best scheme for time-consumption-wise, but it is simple enough for me :)

Comment: Oh I edited my reply like a 30 seconds ago. Coincidence :) I hope my first comment is an answer to your question.

Comment: Sorry for delaying the "accepting process". I didn't know that I could "accept". Not very familiar with SO system.

Answer (score 0):

1. you might dont want to this.
2. if you really want to do this, then
3. it is not really JSP related question, instead it is HTTP related question
4. you can join the content in the array with comma and append the whole string as a query string component in the url.

example:

in a.jsp you have a link:

```
b.jsp?array=1,2,3,4,5
```

in b.jsp you interpret the array string and get an arraylist of:

> [1,2,3,4,5]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But why do you suggest that "I might don't want to this"? Is my architecture a bad idea? And also, can't I just append an ArrayList in the query string?

Comment: just seems a little strange, if the data the in the array is not huge, then it might be ok, if the data is huge, you might want to store the data in server side and just pass a key to the array from page to page. Seems no straightforward to append a 'ArrayList' to a <a>, http dont know 'ArrayList'.

Comment: Storing data in server side seems like a much better idea!! I have no idea how to do that though...Does that require session control? The 2-dimensional ArrayList is dynamically generated by user's request, so I cannot store all the ArrayList beforehand. And to be honest, I don't know how to store anything in the server side. All I know is doGet() and request.getParameter() (I'm a total newbie)

Comment: if it is generated by user, then you cannt store in serverside beforehand. then you have to put it in the query string(for GET), or request body(for POST), and at serverside you interpret it yourself just like i stated  in the answer.

Comment: I am not sure if we are on the same page. User requests a specific data from the server, and the server returns the data in 2-dimensional ArrayList. In this situation do I still have to use either query string or request body?

Comment: The best example of what I want to do is, Google News. In Google News, you can click "all (some_number) news articles" and you get a page of similar news. This is what I want to do.

Comment: "and the server returns the data in 2-dimensional ArrayList." -- then the data is not generated by user, and you dont want to pass the 2dimension ArrayList from one JSP to another JSP. instead it is much easier to do all the things in one JSP.

Comment: I kept the 2 JSP page scheme, but I did a little modification. The first comment to the reply below explains my scheme.